# Cosine Analog to Euler's Reflection Formula (Connecting the Gamma Function to Cosines)

Tags: trigonometry, gamma-function

I'm wondering if there is an analogous equation describing the relation between the Gamma function and cosines, as [Euler's Reduction Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) does for the Gamma function and sines:

$$\Gamma (z) \Gamma (1-z)= \frac{ \pi }{\sin( \pi z)} $$

After looking and not seeing anything in the descriptions and identities for the Gamma function, I tried deriving it myself, starting with the trigonometric identity:

$$\sin( \pi z)^2 + \cos( \pi z)^2 = 1$$

and solving for $\cos (\pi z)$, however, a few steps into the derivation and get lost here:

$$\cos( \pi z) = \pm \frac{ \sqrt{(\Gamma (z) \Gamma (1-z))^{2} - \pi^{2} } }{ \Gamma (z) \Gamma (1-z)}$$

I know that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$, so $(\Gamma(1/2))^{4} = \pi^{2}$ but that may not be helpful.  I'm not sure where to go from here, or if there even is such a relation using cosines.  If there is, I'd like to know what it is, or how to derive it, or at the very least, what it's called.  Does this exist?  Thanks!

**EDIT** I think I wrote the last line of my derivation incorrectly, and should read $\Gamma(1-z)$ not $\Gamma(z-1)$, which I have now changed.

**UPDATE** My understanding from researching this elsewhere is that formula does exist, and specifically exists in terms of Gamma functions of **integers**.  The one answer posted is in terms of 1/2 plus the argument, which is not the version I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you just replace $z$ with $\frac{1}{2}-z$ you get:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+z\right)=\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi z)}.$$

Comment: I had tried that separately using the identities for Gamma(1/2 +/- n) and multiplying them but just got (-4)^n/(4^n). Did I miss something? Otherwise, could I have continued with my original proof and find it that way? And by the way, does this have a name?

Comment: Is there a version that uses just z and not 1/2-z?